# How to improve a model that is consistently underestimating

Tags: estimation, predictive-models, error

I've been trying to predict house prices (real data from my country) and I noticed that initially, errors are centered around zero, but around the $2,500,000 mark, the model starts underestimating prices, at an increasing rate. I'm using a random forest model, which brings the best results.

My question is: is there something I can do to improve estimation on the right tail? I thought about regressing these two variables after the $2,500,000 mark and then using the beta from that regression to re-center those predictions around zero, but doesn't seem to be a very orthodox way. Is there any advice for these cases?

Thanks
[image: Scatterplot]

Comment: Try to model log prices. Note that you will have to accept some bias in the extremes, a phenomenon called "regression to the mean".

Comment: forgot to mention those are log prices, that afterwards had a exponential function applied . So there's no kind of solution to this? Thanks Michael !

Comment: You’re modeling log prices?  How are you getting the predicted price (on the original scale)?

Comment: It's in my reply: I applied an exponential function to them and to `y_test` so both my error and the price are on the original scale

Comment: Could try to resample the dataset. You have a lot of points in the lower interval and less in the upper.

Comment: I imagine you've thought about this, but...apparently no predictors in your model are properly capturing whatever it is that distinguishes a high from a very high price.  Are there any additional predictors available that might do so, even if they are little help with the many lower-priced houses?

Comment: As of now I did almost anything I could. My last attemp was text mining the rough location to obtain dummies of the most common neighborhoods of the 1st and 10th percentiles in the most expensive areas of my data. Even using that, even though results improved a bit, it wasn't enough. There's also the option that there's more measurement error on those observations, because this is data extracted from a website where anyone can submit their houses for sale

Comment: If your model gives unbiased predictions for log price, then exponentiating those will give biased (low) predictions for price.  You need to model price, or else make a smearing adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that a majority of your observations lie below the $2,500,000 mark, and the regression gives greater weighting to observations below this threshold as a result.

Have you considered using a **quantile regression**?

Essentially, this type of regression takes data in quantiles, and generates several regressions based on the quantile under analysis.

The advantage of doing this is it allows for the fact that the number of observations may be uneven across quantiles, and prevents higher values from being skewed downwards by the majority of observations below a certain level.

However, the disadvantage of this method is that one must ensure a sufficient number of observations across each quantile for statistically credible results.

This can be carried out using the **quantreg** package in R, [you can find more detail here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/quantreg.pdf).